# Unable to extract data from json using python

Tags: python

I have the following code so far. The code manages to read the JSON file in python.  However, I am not sure how I can extract the instrument name, bid, and ask prices into their respective dictionaries. Need some help in storing the values into the dictionaries. Also, the instrument name consists of 4 parts.  For example BTC-31JUL20-9250-P.  I would want to split them making it into stable like of format where I can see the ask and bid price together too.

```
import json
import requests

def get_spot_price():
    url = 'https://www.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_index?currency=BTC'
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    global btc_price
    btc_price = data['result'].get('BTC')
    print(btc_price)

def get_call_run():
   
    instrument = {}
    bid_price = {}
    ask_price = {}
    
    url = 'https://www.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_book_summary_by_currency?currency=BTC&kind=option'
    data = requests.get(url).json()    
    print(data)
  
get_spot_price()
get_call_run()
```

Comment: provide the sample json for better answers

Comment: I extracted in from the API. It can found in data under def get_call_run():

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is already in JSON format and converted to a dictionary for you. If you look at the result of second call you will find a dictionary ready for you, it has a `result` key which is a list of python dictionaries each one has the keys you want here is the code to print them all and split the instrument name

```
instrument = []
bid_price = []
ask_price = []

url = 'https://www.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_book_summary_by_currency?currency=BTC&kind=option'
data = requests.get(url).json()
results = data["result"]
for result in results:
    instrument.append(result["instrument_name"].split("-"))
    bid_price.append(result["bid_price"])
    ask_price.append(result["ask_price"])
```